# Raising speech craft through buying and selling

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I found the khajiit caravan to be the most successful way to level my speech.
I'm at speech 83 now and wondering if items that are bartered have any effect on the amount of exp returned. If anyone has any idea please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, congratulations on your first question; in the future, use the tags to determine your game and platform instead of writing it in the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The speech skill increase depends on the base value of the item traded or the difficulty of the bribe or persuasion. When selling items, it is not actually required to receive any gold, only that the transaction takes place. The skill increase only occurs once per transaction. In order to optimize leveling, expensive items in groups of 6 or more should be sold individually, rather than all at once.

[source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Speech)

Comment: Thank you; tried to up +1 your answer but says I need 15 rep

Comment: @Bloodrose if you click the little check mark on this answer, it will mark this accepted so others will know that this is the correct answer. If you hang around the site and gain some rep, you can always come back a upvote answers that helped you.